# What is the Unity Input System equivalent of GetAxis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

I'm trying to get input from my character using the Input System package when I press the left/right arrows keys, however when I read the value of the input it currently snaps between 0, -1, and 1. This is similar to the Input Manager's GetAxisRaw, however, **what I want is to be able to do something more like GetAxis** where it's not instantly 1, but goes through a couple float numbers between 0 and 1 up until 1. Same when it goes back down as well.

**Preferably, I'd like to know if the current Input System has a way to manage that on its own, rather than needing to adjust the input myself through any mathematical formulas over time.**

What I'm trying to achieve is smooth movement left and right, where for a split second or so the character picks up speed before they reach the max, and where letting go they also still slide for a split second before stopping. Since what I'm doing is setting the velocity equal to the multiplied value of the speed (**rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(//input value * movement speed, rigidbody.velocity.y))**.

Of course I understand that if there is no way to create a sort of "ramping" effect to the snapping numbers, I could make it an acceleration speed instead (**rigidbody.velocity += new Vector2(blah blah))**. The issue being I then need to insert extra code to set a cap for the speed, and to slow down the velocity when I let go so my character doesn't slide like they're on ice.

Answer (score 0):

**No, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to GetAxis for the Unity Input System package**, however I did attempt to emulate it. The Unity Docs note that Pasted from Unity Docs "the Horizontal and Vertical ranges change from 0 to +1 or -1 with increase/decrease in 0.05f steps."

**So I used Mathf.Lerp(a, b, t)** (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) where my starting value (a) was 0, and my ending value (b) was the input (whether it be 1 or -1). My interpolation value (t) starts at 0 and I would add 0.05 to it each frame. This was a bit too slow, so I multiplied it by an int that I called inputSensitivity.

For the visual learners:

```
[SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 5f;

    private InputMaster inputActions;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

    static float movementIncrementOverTime = 0;
    [SerializeField] int inputSensitivity = 100;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputActions = new InputMaster();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        inputActions.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        inputActions.Disable();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Read the movement value

        float moveInput = Running();
        inputActions.Player.Movement.canceled += Movement_canceled;

        //Move the player
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * moveSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }

    private float Running()
    {
        float moveInput = inputActions.Player.Movement.ReadValue<float>();
        switch(moveInput)
        {
            case 1:
                moveInput = Mathf.Lerp(0, moveInput, movementIncrementOverTime);
                movementIncrementOverTime += (0.05f * inputSensitivity) * Time.deltaTime;
                break;

            case -1:
                moveInput = Mathf.Lerp(0, moveInput, movementIncrementOverTime);
                movementIncrementOverTime += (0.05f * inputSensitivity) * Time.deltaTime;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return moveInput;
    }

    private void Movement_canceled(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        movementIncrementOverTime = 0;
    }
```

The Running() function is the key here, it makes it so that instead of snapping to 1 and -1, it gradually moves up to those values. Then, in the Update() function the line of code `inputActions.Player.Movement.canceled += Movement_canceled;` checks for when I release the key and resets my `static float movementIncrementOverTime` to 0 so I can once again ramp up speed when I decided to move in the opposite direction, or if I stand still and start walking again.

**The only issue**, which I have yet to fix, is that I haven't figured out how to get the character to slide slightly when you let go of the key, instead of instantly stopping when you let go.